# Redirecting to subfolder

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink, apache2, subdirectory

I have my website **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** and i have a page at **[www.example.com/site](http://www.example.com/site)**.

If i create a link at that website like this `<a href="/something.html">button</a>` then it redirects me to **[www.example.com/something.html](http://www.example.com/something.html)**.

Is there any solution to this **without changing the href link**, so it redirects to **[www.example.com/site/something.html](http://www.example.com/site/something.html)**?

I'm using apache2 to host the site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="/something.html">button</a>`

You need to appoint the folder, so you could do:

`<a href="site/something.html">button</a>`

or you could do:

`<a href="https://www.example.com/site/something.html">button</a>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're already in the `site` folder when you try to go to `something.html` which is also in the `site` folder, you would use

```
<a href="something.html">button</a>
```

The slash `/` in front of your link address is telling the browser to go to the root directory `www.example.com` and then find `something.html`. That's why you end up with `www.example.com/something.html`.

So again, just use `<a href="something.html">button</a>`.